# batch file : stop a processes

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that call a program , but I want to stop this program after h hours 
for example my batch will have this code

```
@echo off
........
.......
............
call myprogram.exe
```

is there a way to stop myprogram.exe after h hours ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
REM delay for 36000 seconds (10 hours)
FOR /l %%a in (36000,-1,1) do (Echo closing in %%as&ping -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>NUL)
REM delete the program using it's PID
FOR /f "tokens=2" %a in ('tasklist ^| find "notepad.exe"') do tskill %a
```

using ping means it works in XP, Vista and 7 *(and, I would assume Win 8)*

Comment: this wont work , for example if I call myprogram.exe it wont execute other commands after this one until myprogram.exe stop

Comment: use `start myprogram.exe` - this will continue executing the batch file after the program starts. You actually have to specify `/W` or `/WAIT` to make it pause until the program has finished

Answer (score 2):

This would be much easier, assuming you are using Vista or above

```
start myprogram.exe
timeout /t 3600
taskkill /im myprogram.exe /f
```

Just replace the `3600` with your time delay (in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009) in a batch file:

```
taskkill /IM myprogram.exe
```

As far as stopping the program after it has run for h hours, I'm not sure how to invoke that.  If you had a specific time that you wanted to stop it at, you could use something as simple as a Windows scheduled task.

Otherwise, you could try using a service management application like [FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com/) to set up myprogram.exe as a Windows service, and schedule it for shutdown after h hours.  Unfortunately FireDaemon isn't free, but it would definitely be up to the task.